# Tabulator 4.1, Change text color of a row bases on a condition

Tags: tabulator

I have a simple table where I am able to change the background color of the row by: `row.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#A6A6DF";`

How do I change the text color of the row? I tried used `rowTextColor`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ***color*** style property:

```
row.getElement().style.color= "#FF0000";
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!